# How does this clean up the empty space in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

```
void empty_spaces(char array[]){
 int j=0,i=0,n=0;
 n=strlen(array);
 while(i<n){
    if(array[i]==' '){
        j=i;
        while(j<n){
             array[j]=array[j+1];
             ++j;
        }
        --n;
    }else
         ++i;
 }
 if(n>15)
         n=15;
 array[n]='\0';
}
```

Could someone explain me, this code? This function cleans up the empty spaces in array, but could someone explain me exactly what it works?

Comment: well, you could always run this in a debugger and step through it to try to understand what it does. After that, you can come back here with a specific question...

Comment: What exactly is the source of your confusion in this code?

Comment: It appears to compress out all the blanks.  Then truncate the array is a length of 15.

Comment: A better question is how the function should be written to be linear instead of quadratic. The `if(n>15)` is an enigma, too.

Comment: Also, i reckon the source is written fairly chaotically, but nothing un-figure-outable, just might seem unclean and jumbled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It loops over every character in the array, removing all ' ' (space) characters.  The inner loop is what does the erasing.  When the outer loop finds a space character, the inner loop "shifts" the rest of the array to the left one index, overwriting the space.

Answer (score 5):

It's a rather flabby attempt at a function that removes spaces from a string. The problem with the code is that it has gratuitous iteration and it turns an O(n) algorithm into an O(n^2) algorithm.

Rather than trying to understand the code you have I feel it is best to do it the efficient and simple way. Like this.

```
void empty_spaces(char str[])
{
    char *src = str; 
    char *dst = str;

    while (*src)
    {
        if (*src != ' ')
        {
            *dst = *src;
            dst++;
        }
        src++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

We perform a single pass across the string with two pointers, `src` and `dst`. When a non-space character is encountered it is copied from source to destination. Maintaining two separate pointers into the array avoids the spurious iteration from your code.

I ignored the `n>15` part of your code. The effect of that is that the string is always truncated to have length no greater than 15 characters, but quite why that would be done is mysterious to me. It surely shouldn't be mixed up in this function.

Since I've not really answered the question as asked, but since I hope this is useful to you, I have made the answer community wiki.

Comment: `while (src)`, are you sure? :p

Comment: Doesn't answer the question but "*This answer is useful*" :-)

Comment: @fge Thanks a lot. Compiling and testing in my head failed yet again!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You probably also want `*dst = '\0'`.

Comment: Yes, got that now, and thanks also to @Jonathan Leffler for the same point in an edit

Answer (score 1):

A rewritten and commented version of the above:

```
//....
n = strlen(array); // n is the number of characters in the array up to the final 0
while (i < n) {
    if (array[i] != ' ') { // not a space
        i++;               // next char,
        continue;          // continue
    }

    j = i; // j is the current array index

    while (j < n) {        // while there are chars left...
        array[j] = array[j+1]; // copy the next character into the current index
        j++;
    }
    n--;                   // and remove one from the string len since a space is removed
}
```

The code after that limits the string length to 15 before returning.

So this code removes spaces *and* possibly truncates the string to 15 chars only.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, as soon as the loop encounters `' '` character (space), it moves all the elements of array one place ' left ', therefore replacing the space with the following character.

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your answer. And generally provide sample code.